# Refer to first argument type of the current function

Tags: typescript, constructor, typescript-generics

So I'm trying to acheive something here and I can't figure out how to do this.

I want to refer to the type of the first argument of a function and get the correct infered type. It's better explained with an example.

```js
type AllFood = 'grass' | 'meat' | 'grain' | 'corn' | 'tofu';

type Constructable<T> = new (...args: any) => T;

// I have a basic abstract class upon which a lot of class are built
abstract class Animal<Food extends AllFood = AllFood> { 
    public food: Food;

    constructor(food: Food) { 
        this.food = food;
    }
}

// I have a lot of like these that supports only a specific subset of food
class DollyTheCow extends Animal<'grass' | 'grain' | 'corn'> {}

// Now I have a factory function to build the classes with the params it receives
function createClass(
SomeAnimalClass: Constructable<Animal>, // <- The specific constructor
food: InstanceType<typeof SomeAnimalClass>['food'] // <- I want this to be typed according to the specific constructor just above, but it always fallsback to AllFood even when specifying a specific constructor that supports only a subset. 
) {
    const animal = new SomeAnimalClass(food);
}

createClass(DollyTheCow, 'meat'); // This should fail telling me DollyTheCow can't eat meat
createClass(DollyTheCow, 'grass'); // This should be fine
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=26&pln=20&pc=29#)

Any idea on how I can acheive this? I tried A LOT of different options, but basically nothing works. I want to avoid adding a generic to the `createClass` function since it'll be redundant.

Comment: What would be redundant about making `createClass` generic if the generic parameter is inferred? You wouldn't have to declare the generic all over the place, since it can be inferred by argument type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without generics. Generics enable `createClass` to declare that one argument depends on another argument. Without generics you can't know the type of arguments more specifically than they are declared.

That means that if the type is `Animal`, the type system cannot ever know what kind of animal, without runtime checks, or generics.

That said, a tiny change to add an inferred generic fixes this.

```
function createClass<T extends Animal>(
    SomeAnimalClass: Constructable<T>,
    food: T['food']
) {
    const animal = new SomeAnimalClass(food);
}

createClass(DollyTheCow, 'meat'); // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=4&pln=22&pc=46#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAYge2QEygXigcgOYBOAhgM4k5QA+uAthEcBdfsQJYB2TuAxsgZ1VzBkAMwCuOANwAoaaEhQAwsnYlgBMd2BEARnAgAeACoA+LFHYQA7lAAUAOkdECeEgC4oRdiACUWM0Yy0gD0wVAAklAAFkQAbtBEUDqkrNyeOmrEWlDccKQkUGJgKlBWUalRnlBwyMBQojl5ZJ4E0DpirHDA0rqZRNm5+bDsrDREcAYo6FAQAB7AEOxoBfBIqBjYq1NoZgDeUNJQR1BgYnqpUCLrHttBxzkqmZrCBLZX6DfrfvuH98fA5RI9neG0u6xk9wAvtJoSEwpEYvEqjU6g04KwANbQAEQEjYmJ1EhFYoEYAFFRwEBVEiQbisEQXIkZCCokRg9DSQbNAAiyAQICMUQgyhscwWSxWIzGExY+S4so48t4-Bwe1hoSgADlkDYEXEEpd+i8qeJ2FpWCVhEkOnAMDjGvlcaVWACoPawM4iDQCi6oK1uBBWPESNJTeaStxWgxhU0SMYZvNFsthqNxiZbL8jgBlZB0GBS8aKWMeZSqdTPXT6YwmAA0UA1BgAtFBBdAaRA6Qy0rwyxotHxM+y0B4jABtHAgnAAXXrYSbEVKXjqANYBStOmx4AgGH6yrQHDwbuQbqFUHbnYuPae-YIUAAVmI1OlkPE6+06r7xlYiCACiJxnAJDJNwGJHrACDbDM8TsKUQowee9IgAe1K0vSl6POWN4ngwZ7EnwZL1OwlLUmceLAPYBzfIOV51F4qZwOYlg2DmeYFnARb5G8XwyLCkb0AsHFkLYvL8q2Ip1jgdAMDgPiSLOsAuGIdDsKybpbrgABEUnABpFCrhYtSeGQrB4OwlbYseHrEHQCy3g08jQDgGmEPkGmCM5bDsG51AacqXk4JyUYCbGwl8pSYk6hJLlkDJckagA6nwGIkEAA)

The generic parameter allows you to forward `DollyTheCow` into `Constructable<T>` and then lets you get its food.

I'm not sure what you are concerned about with making `createClass` generic, but I'm fairly certain that *cannot* be done without making it generic.

Comment: This seems to be doing what I want, but I don't fully understand why you can call the class without passing a generic type here since the generics has no default value.
I tought `createClass(DollyTheCow, 'meat')` would fail and I'd had to use `createClass<DollyTheCow>(DollyTheCow, 'meat')`. Which is why I though is was redundant!

Comment: Generic functions allow their generic types to be inferred from arguments. [Read up on the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for generics that has other examples of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

you can add the food-type to your `Constructable` and `createClass` function, like this:

```
type AllFood = 'grass' | 'meat' | 'grain' | 'corn' | 'tofu';

type Constructable<T, TF extends AllFood> = new (food: TF, ...args: any) => T;

// I have a basic abstract class upon which a lot of class are built
abstract class Animal<Food extends AllFood = AllFood> { 
    public food: Food;

    constructor(food: Food) { 
        this.food = food;
    }
}

// I have a lot of like these that supports only a specific subset of food
class DollyTheCow extends Animal<'grass' | 'grain' | 'corn'> {}

// Now I have a factory function to build the classes with the params it receives
function createClass<T extends AllFood>(
SomeAnimalClass: Constructable<Animal<T>, T>, // <- The specific constructor
food: T // <- I want this to be typed according to the specific constructor just above, but it always fallsback to AllFood even when specifying a specific constructor that supports only a subset. 
) {
    const animal = new SomeAnimalClass(food);
}

createClass(DollyTheCow, 'meat'); // COMPILE ERROR
createClass(DollyTheCow, 'grass'); // This should be fine
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAYge2QEygXigcgOYBOAhgM4k5QA+uAthEcBdfsQJYB2TuAxsgZ1VzBkAMwCuOANwAoaaEhQAwsnYlgBMd2BEARnAgAeACoAaKEcRQIAD2AR2aErAQp0APixR2EAO5QAFCKoaABc5ohmAHTRRAR4JGFE7CAAlFgeRjLSAPTZUACSUAAWRABu0ERQOqSs3FC6asRaUNxwpE5iYCpQPkW1RfVQcMjAUKItbWT1BNA6YqxwwNIN6kTNre2w7Kw0RHAGrhg2dg5O8EjBnueHHgDeUNJQT1BgYnq1UEHoYYdZzy0qRqaYQEQLBH7BNL3R7-Z7APokSJfDDYZEyf4AX2kWJyeUKJXKg2Go3GcFYAGtoPCICQqSVRiROl0CMAnCo4CBBiRINxWCIPoydLSSSJPsFpBspgARZAIEBGIoQZR+Y72RxbHZ7AwsdpcHUcPW8fg4O443JQAByyD8+LKFU+axBnPE7C0rG6wiq8zgGGpE3aNJ6rHhUD9YFiRBoTmDUBm3AgrHKJGkLrd3W4MwYSsmJGMVlsarOLmCbn80gAysg6DBtrs4Ioc2FlKp1MDdPoDDXNfsjG4zL2zOaDABacyKqDciC8-l1XgtjRaPgp8HmKBD0eFHxJUbw1hOT06KngCAYNZGtAcPCh5Ch8eT6cfOdAxcEKAAKzEanqOmQ5TMc1GGM9i3EAnBEPY4BIapuHJa9nAudArHKdgekVFD7z5EBLy5Hk+UfQFWxfW8GAnJk+FZMZ2A5Lk3mFSIHihGEnifUYkm7TxvD8Stq1rPYG3aMF0BSGQcQzeg7H4sh-BlOUFSVa0zBwOgGBwYS1zyBU9wnIpkDEH0HQWUMIAQbC6CgGSOTk5UWiSHBRnEqBlKWMSs0kkhpNlSzFWVRTCF1NTzU0pwSB0vSMEPT4OAgIA)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but like I said I'm trying to avoid using a generics because it would become very redundant all over my app. My example here is an over-simplification, but in reality I'd have to add a few generics in a row for a functions that's being used hundreds of times.

Comment: Sorry, turns out your anwser was good too, but Alex Wayne's answer is the one that made me understand!

Comment: I agree that Wayne's answer is better. If you think that answers are useful, you can upvote them (click on the up-arrow)